# Debugging information present in my siverlight 4 application?

Tags: silverlight, debugging

When i run my silverlight 4 application, there information about session, trace information, headers collection, Server Variables etc...

Dose anyone know how i can disable that?

cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Compile and run the release build rather than the debug build.